# Как сделать вывод смайликов в текстовом поле RichEdit

Tags: c#

Добрый день. Хочу сделать программу, которая бы текстовые сокращения вида ":),:(" и так далее по нажатию по кнопке на форме переводила в смайлики.
На саму форму для принятия входящих данных я добавил обычный textbox а вот для вывода уже самих смайликов у меня компонент RichTextBox.
Набор смайликов у меня статический в том плане, что это просто картинки формата png.
Скажу сразу, я уже пытался найти подобную информацию и нашел. [Inserting Smiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28784655/c-sharp-inserting-smileys-in-richtextbox-inserts-some-and-ignores-others)

Но я не совсем понимаю, в какую часть кода, что помещать. Да и у меня немного другие требования. Именно после клика по кнопке, что бы проводилась подобная замена и помещалась в RichEditBox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добрый вечер, на самом деле в том примере, что вы оставили ссылкой имеется весь необходимый код для реализации вашей цели.
Прочитав ваши требования я составил небольшую форму

[image: Форма приложения]

После взяв исходный код из примера немного его подправил и получил необходимый результат. Логика здесь такова: весь текст из textBox1 перенёс в richTextBox1, далее уже в самом richTextBox1 производится замена символов на картинки(смайлы), так же можно очистить textBox1, но это на ваше усмотрение.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Надеюсь это удовлетворит ваши требования.Весь код оставлю ниже. Задавай вопросы, постараюсь ответить.

```
private void add_smileys(TextBox tb,RichTextBox rtb)
    {
        var smileys = new Dictionary<string, Image>()
            {
                { @":)", Resources.in_smile },
                { @">:(", Resources.in_angry },
            };
        //Изменения здесь. Очищаем поле richTextBox1 перед его использованием
        richTextBox1.Text = null;
        //Вставляем текст из textBox1 в richTextBox1
        rtb.Text = tb.Text;

        foreach (var smiley in smileys)
        {
            add_smiley(rtb, smiley.Key, smiley.Value);
        }
    }

    private void add_smiley(RichTextBox rtb, string token, Image smiley)
    {

        while (true)
        {

            var selectionStart = rtb.Find(token, RichTextBoxFinds.WholeWord);

            if (selectionStart < 0) break;

            try
            {
                rtb.SelectionStart = selectionStart;
                rtb.SelectionLength = token.Length;

                Clipboard.SetImage(smiley);
                rtb.Paste();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        add_smileys(textBox1,richTextBox1);
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо:)
Единственное еще есть но. Обращение к ресурсам к самим смайликам. У меня через Properties.Resources только так видит смайлики. Может я не правильно что то добавляю?

Comment: А ты в какой Resuources добавлял? который в самой форме или общий в проекте?а воообще это вроде не критично, укажи ссылку просто на Properties

Comment: через свойства проекта закидываю. Но думаю это не критично. Так как все прекрасно работает и из Properties. Еще раз спасибо за помощь:)